# Is this solution using Cauchy's integral formula correct?

Tags: solution-verification, contour-integration, complex-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

Cauchy's integral formula is:

$$f(z_0)n(\gamma,z_0)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_\gamma\frac{f(z)}{z-z_0}dz$$

The problem I had to solve was:

$$\int_\gamma \frac{dz}{(z^2+9)(z+9)};\gamma:|z|=4$$

My thoughts were that we could write: $f(z)=\frac{1}{z^2+9}$ and $z_0=-9$, therefore $z_0$ is outside of $\gamma$ and as such $n(\gamma,-9)=0$. Therefore:

$$\int_\gamma \frac{dz}{(z^2+9)(z+9)}=0$$

Since whenever a result in math is $0$ you have to be wary, I'm asking here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That integral is equal to $-\frac{\pi i}{45}$. In fact, the function $f$ has $2$ and only two singularities at the region bounded by the curve $|z|=4$: at $\pm3i$. Since$$\operatorname{res}_{z=3i}f(z)=-\frac1{180}-\frac i{60}\quad\text{and}\quad\operatorname{res}_{z=-3i}f(z)=-\frac1{180}+\frac i{60},$$your integral is equal to$$2\pi i\left(-\frac1{180}-\frac i{60}-\frac1{180}+\frac i{60}\right)=-\frac{\pi i}{45}.$$The problem with your approach is that $f$ is not defined at all points of the region bounded by the curve $|z|=4$.

---

You can also solve the problem doing a partial fraction decomposition. It turns out that$$f(z)=\frac\alpha{z+9}+\frac\beta{z-3i}+\frac\gamma{z+3i}$$with$$\alpha=\frac{1}{90},\quad\beta=-\frac{1}{180}-\frac{i}{60},\quad\text{and}\quad\gamma=-\frac{1}{180}+\frac{i}{60}.$$Now, you can apply Cauchy's integral formula.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the problem with my approach is, can you explain a bit further?

Comment: Cauchy's integral theorem states that if $f$ is an analytical function whose domain contains the region of $\Bbb C$ bounded by a curve $\gamma$, and if $z_0$ belongs to the domain of $f$, then$$\frac1{2\pi i}\oint_\gamma\frac{f(z)}{z-z_0}\,\mathrm dz=f(z_0)n(\gamma,z_0).$$In your case, $\pm3i$ do not belong to the domain of $f$, but they do belong to the region bounded by the curve $|z|=4$. Therefore, the theorem does not apply in this situation.

Comment: @MartinArgerami I reread the entire theorem and yeah, that's right. However, the question explicitly asked to use Cauchy's integral formula, but if the function isn't analytic, what else could I do?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Perfect explanation, but the problem's asking to use the theorem, so what can I do? Simply state this?

Comment: I've added another answer.

Comment: Alright, so as a last check, the reason why you can apply the theorem here is that you're applying it to three different functions that happen to be 1, and therefore are analytic in all of the complex plane (including the region bounded by gamma), right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.